# Multiple data constructors using same pattern

Tags: haskell

I have the following data definitions:

```
data Listr a = Nil | Cons a (Listr a) deriving Show
data Listl a = Nil | Cons (Listl a) a deriving Show
```

Haskell complains about `Multiple declarations of ‘Cons’`. (It will complain about Nil as well).
Is this not supported by Haskell? How would one go about declaring something like the above?
Of course I could use:

```
data Listr a = Nill | Consl a (Listr a) deriving Show
data Listl a = Nilr | Consr (Listl a) a deriving Show
```

But I would prefer the first.

Comment: No, Haskell does not allow that. You can sometimes emulate something like it using classy prisms from the lens package, but that’s usually used for composing algebraic datatypes, not ad-hoc name overloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by Haskell. If you absolutely must have two types with a constructor of the same name, you may do so by putting them in different modules. I strongly recommend that you do not get in the practice of doing this, as it can be quite confusing unless you reliably qualify any ambiguous names, even when they are technically not imported in an ambiguous way.

I have enjoyed defining

```
data Tsil a = Lin | Snoc (Tsil a) a
```

on occasion; you may like to steal my naming.

Comment: I like the names :)